# Обтекание текстом адаптивной картинки Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, responsive

Подскажите, как сделать обтекание картинки текстом используя сетку бутстрап?
Для картинки использую класс img-responsive.

Comment: использовать классы - pull-right or pull-left

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: Какое обтекание? Пример желаемого результата можете предоставить?

Comment: Нужно чтобы картинка была прижата к правой стенке, а текст обтекал её слева. Но картинка должна быть респонсив. Всё в контейнере.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5cvs9ye6/

Comment: @Александр, если ответ помог Вам в решении задачи, пожалуйста, отметьте его галкой, расположенной слева, под стрелками голосования.

Answer (score 1):

Класс `img-responsive` задаёт:

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

А класс `pull-right` перебивает значение для `float`:

```
float: right !important;
```

Чтобы картинка меняла размеры, зададим ей ширину через проценты. И настроим, чтобы на узком экране картинка занимала всю ширину колонки. Проверьте, что получилось:

```css
.width-40-pct {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .width-40-pct {
    max-width: 40%;
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x200" class="img-responsive pull-right width-40-pct" alt="" />

      <div class="alert alert-danger visible-xs">
        Картинка прижмется к правому краю, когда экран станет шире 767 пикселей.
      </div>
      
      <p>   слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова
      слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова
      слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова
      слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова
      слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова
      слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова
      слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова
      слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова слова
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      новости новости новости новости новости новости новости новости новости
      новости новости новости новости новости новости новости новости новости
      новости новости новости новости новости новости новости новости новости
      новости новости новости новости новости новости новости новости новости
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```